# How to extract the deepest data from a flattened json?

Tags: python

I have a flattened json data like this, aka **input data**:

```
data = ['a', 'a-aa', 'a-aa-aaa', 'a-aa-aab', 'a-aa-aab-aaba', 'b', 'b-ba', 'b-ba-baa']
```

And I only want the deepest data as follows, aka **output data**:

```
a-aa-aaa
a-aa-aab-aaba
b-ba-baa
```

Explain: in this sample, the data tree is as follows:

```
| a
  | a-aa
    | a-aa-aaa
    | a-aa-aab
      | a-aa-aab-aab
| b
  | b-ba
    | b-ba-baa
```

I want the deepest traverse, so the process is mostly like this:

```
| a
 | a-aa
   | a-aa-aaa(traverse over)
   | a-aa-aab
     | a-aa-aab-aab(traverse over)
| b
 | b-ba
   | b-ba-baa(traverse over)
```

So, end of that, we can get the output data.
I know this process can be just a little simple to you, but I overcomplicate my thinking. So, if you know the answer, please tell me. God Bless You!

Comment: Please explain the logic that selects the item to be included in the output!

Comment: OK! I have reedited this question, you can see more details of the logic of the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can recursively build the tree using `collections.defaultdict` and then select the leaves:

```
import collections
data = ['a', 'a-aa', 'a-aa-aaa', 'a-aa-aab', 'a-aa-aab-aaba', 'b', 'b-ba', 'b-ba-baa']
def get_groups(d):
  _d = collections.defaultdict(list)
  for a, [j, *k] in d:
     _d[j].append((a, k))
  for a, b in _d.items():
     k, vals = [x for x, y in b if not y], [(x, y) for x, y in b if y]
     if k and not vals:
        yield from k
     else:
        yield from get_groups(vals)
     
print(list(get_groups([(i, i.split('-')) for i in data])))
```

Output:

```
['a-aa-aaa', 'a-aa-aab-aaba', 'b-ba-baa']
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with list comprehensions and it might be faster. But, there is a way to do this in O(n) time, so try:

```py
def get_deepest_data(data):
    _max = data[0].count("-")
    deepest_data = list([data[0]])

    for i in data[1:]:
        count = data[i].count("-")

        if count > _max:
            _max = count
            deepest_data = list([data[i]])
        elif count == _max:
            deepest_data.append(data[i])

    return deepest_data
```

Comment: I am little confused, forgive me, you can use this program to generate the right output data?